# redirect not working after Asp.net Forms Authetication Login using Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm trying to login by storing username and password in web.config file as below

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Admin Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx">
    <credentials>
      <user name="Admin"  password="123"  />

    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

And I wrote this code on submit button

```
 if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(TxtUsername.Text, TxtPassword.Text))
    {

        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(TxtUsername.Text, false));
    }
```

but it's not get redirected.. Any suggestion..?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) before redirecting.

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(TxtUsername.Text, TxtPassword.Text))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(TxtUsername.Text, false);
    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(TxtUsername.Text, false));
}
```

Comment: Have you setup an `<authorization>` section in your web.config?  You need to tell ASP.Net to deny users to a certain page, which will cause a redirect to your login form.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @dana: if there is no `authorization` forms authentication and redirect should work normally..

Answer (score 2):

Actual culprit is your `credentials` tag..
change it to following.. it should work for you..

```
..
<credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
     ...
```

and also use

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TxtUsername.Text, false);
```

after authentication, which will set authCookie and redirect to either requested page or to your default page..